# Does a law for A in boolean algebra hold true for not A as well?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Okay, so according to associative law: (A + B + C) = (A + B) + C

So, could I also assume that ~(A + B + C) = ~A + ~B + ~C = ~(A + B) + ~C

Where "~" means NOT and "+" means OR.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)? According to this law, $\neg(A + B) = \neg A\neg B\neq \neg A + \neg B$.

Comment: From your comment, I can see that I don't understand it well enough. 
From what I understood, it applies to TWO terms. ~a + ~b = ~a*~b
I don't see how I can apply that to three terms at my current level of understanding.

Comment: Why, yes... yes it does. Quite succinctly as well. Thank you.